# FFMPEG Video with extremely long audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

The issue with ffmpeg.

1. A 10 second video plays for 3 hours due to audio also the video is frozen on the first frame
2. If I remove the audio using the **-an** flag then the video duration is correct and the video plays corretly, but I would still like to have the audio in the video.

Any idea?

Here is my FFMPEGargs

```
   ffmpeg -i video.webm -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: sounds like audio is somehow corrupt ... I would extract out the audio and clip its length to match video's length then add audio back into a new video

Comment: @ScottStensland thank you, how would I do that per say? got any examples.

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to extract the audio:
First, get the duration of the video with following command:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal input.webm
```

Sample output:

```
01:28:33.52
```

Then, use ffmpeg's -ss option to stop there:

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.webm -ss TIMECODE -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

where `TIMECODE` must be replaced with the time from the first command.

Comment: [`ffprobe` can directly give you the duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) so you don't need to use `grep`.